# URL parameters to open PDF with two pages up (side by side)

Tags: html, url, pdf

What are the parameters to specify that the browser open a PDF with two pages up (side by side)?

I found documentation for zoom and for bookmarks but not for two pages up.

> http://example.org/doc.pdf#pagemode=bookmarks&zoom=50

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please. Two pages up! You want to open two pdfs? or you want to open it at page number 2? or you want to open same pdf two times? Shed some light.

Comment: Acrobat reader has a feature to show two pages of the document side by side.  What is the parameter to send with the URL to have the document open with the first two pages side by side.